# How to create custom gauge chart?

Tags: html, css, angular

I am develop an app using Angular framework. I need to create a gauge chart like below, I have tried ngx-chart but the gauge chart is quite different with the requirement. Any ideas?

[custom gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/esPY9.png)

Comment: I'd suggest you might want to create an angular custom component and use SVG (or canvas) to display this.

Answer (score 0):

At first run `npm install angular-gauge-chart`

// your appmodule:

```
import { GaugeChartModule } from 'angular-gauge-chart'

imports: [
    GaugeChartModule,
]
```

// your tmpl:

```
<rg-gauge-chart
    [canvasWidth]="canvasWidth"
    [needleValue]="needleValue"
    [centralLabel]="centralLabel"
    [options]="options"
    [name]="name"
    [bottomLabel]="bottomLabel">
</rg-gauge-chart>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular-google-charts or angular-highcharts to accomplish your task. Angular Google charts are a wrapper of the Google Charts library for Angular 6+.

If you are gonna use Gauge chart in angular, then you have to install the package. After that import it into app.module.ts

```
npm install angular-google-charts
```

This 'high charts js' is a charting library based on SVG. 'highcharts' is extremely feature-rich than the Gauge chart. It will help to more customize your charts. So if you are gonna use 'highcharts', you have to install bellow packages.

```
npm install angular-highcharts@6.2.6
npm install highcharts@4.2.5
```

After that import it into app.module.ts.
By referring to the below article you will get a good idea about how the above-mentioned charts are working. 
[enter link description here](https://medium.com/@sunnysun_5694/how-to-create-impressive-looking-gauge-charts-using-angular-6-8f91dfd6fc5c)